# Set up PIXI.js with Typescript and Live Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, pixi.js

So, noob question. I currently have a project done in plain Javascript with PIXI.js however I do not get type anotations or Intellisense in my vscode ide. I'm importing the library as [the guide](https://pixijs.io/guides/basics/getting-started.html) shows.

```
<script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.js"></script>
```

Then I open the HTML file with Live Server.

My code is starting to grow large and for obvious reasons and I want to have intellisense in my code and type anotations. I also want to migrate all my code to TypeScript, but I dont want to manually compile all of my `.ts` files everytime i make a change. What is the best way to setup this?

Comment: If you want to get serious with Pixi.js then im afraid you must dip your toes in Typescript. But dont worry - its simple! Try this excellent tutorial: https://www.pixijselementals.com/#getting-started , or those boilerplates: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v5-Boilerplate or https://github.com/miltoncandelero/HelloPixi

Comment: ` I dont want to manually compile all of my .ts files everytime i make a change.` - you can setup so called "hot reload" and then you dont need to manually rebuild your files during local development. It should rebuild your files automatically after change in matter of seconds. There is many docs on internet about how to setup it using Webpack or other bundler (not necessarily related to pixi.js - just to js / node.js in general).